# Understanding a REST/CURL manual

Tags: php, curl

I've been trying to Google about this, but it's hard to be precise it seems. I'm using a service called Attendium that has an API documentation I've just got lost with:

http://docs.attendium.apiary.io/

Under Resources > GuestLists Collection it says that I could do this with PHP:

```
GET https://www.attendium.com/rest/v4/guestLists(?anyOfUsers*, anyOfEvents*, anyOfPermissions*)
```

The thing is: I'm not sure what this part resembles "(?anyOfUsers*, anyOfEvents*, anyOfPermissions*)". Should I replace something, add an ID, should I use more cURL opts, etc?

I hope to leave this level of beginner state fairly quickly. (:

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the whole right frame and you'll understand (they are possible parameters, btw).

Comment: http://screencloud.net/v/EGlE

Comment: That makes sense, Charlotte, but I'm still confused if it's correct, since the output I get from the whole example is just: string(0) ""

Comment: @Erik Blomqvist `curl -vvv https://www.attendium.com/rest/v4/guestLists?anyOfUsers=2d59ec9c-f167-457a-aafa-b161cc8d4580 -o output.txt` returns an empty list in json format. Is this not what you expect?